# Is there a way to copy the security groups of an Azure Devops Repo to another Azure DevOps repository?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We are migrating our repositories from Gitlab to Azure. Since the grouping of repositories are absent in Azure DevOps, we need to set permissions manually for individual repositories.
Is there any way to copy the permissions of one repository as a template, so that we could stretch the same template across multiple repositories, thereby reducing the manual work?

Any suggestions/ideas are welcome.